# ld: duplicate symbol _x in /users/.... ERROR

Tags: iphone, ios, linker-errors

I have 2 different classes but same primitive type declaration as you see below

```
int x = 0;
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

if I change one of them name "x" to "y" there is no error? WHY? seperate classes same variable whats the problem???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the variable x is shared among classes. I think (but never tried) if you declare extern int x in another file, you could share the x variable.

Try static int x = 0. In general, always declare an internal class variable as static unless you want to share it with another file.

Comment: I got it but I can not understand why obj-c allow the access primitive type from another class it must be forbidden because thats the why static keyword exist..

Comment: This is inherited from the normal C.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the question. As Says , because the variable x is shared among classes. Modify the variable x to another name.